# How to use ListView, Layout, item and group template in asp.net with twitter bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I need help with the layout and binding of ListView control in asp.net.  I have a catalogue page, that should only display 6 images per page, with its relevant information.

The problem is this.  I am a bit confused as to how to create the layout.

If all of this design was done with an HTML table, it would have been fairly easy to achieve what I want to accopmplish, as can be seen [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24570/Complete-ListView-in-ASP-NET-3-5).

I am using twitter bootstrap, and the design is not in tables.  Below is my code that produces the look I want.

```
<div class="categories row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="category1">
            <img id="myImageHolder" runat="server" class="image1" alt="" src="../img/metal_candle.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <div class="button">
                <button class="square" type="button">Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>Description:</li>
                <li>Colour:</li>
                <li>Price:</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span4">
        <div class="category1">
            <img class="image1" alt="" src="../img/metal_candle.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <div class="button">
                <button class="square" type="button">Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>Description:</li>
                <li>Colour: </li>
                <li>Price:</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="category1">
            <img class="image1" alt="" src="../img/metal_candle.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <div class="button">
                <button class="square" type="button">Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>Description:</li>
                <li>Colour: </li>
                <li>Price:</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="categories row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="category1">
            <img class="image1" alt="" src="../img/metal_candle.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <div class="button">
                <button class="square" type="button">Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>Description:</li>
                <li>Colour: </li>
                <li>Price:</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="category1">
            <img class="image1" alt="" src="../img/metal_candle.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <div class="button">
                <button class="square" type="button">Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>Description:</li>
                <li>Colour: </li>
                <li>Price:</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="category1">
            <img class="image1" alt="" src="../img/metal_candle.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <div class="button">
                <button class="square" type="button">Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>Description:</li>
                <li>Colour: </li>
                <li>Price:</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I use the Listview, together with the layout template, item template and group template to  produce the above look, but also allow paging and data binding?

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to achieve this.

```
<asp:ListView ID="category1" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div class="categories row">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="category1">
                        <img class="image1" alt="No Image" src="CatalogueImages/<%# Eval("ImageName") %>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="details">
                        <div class="button">
                            <button class="square" type="button">Add to Cart</button>
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><%# Eval("ImageDescription") %></li>
                            <li>Colour: <%# Eval("Color") %></li>
                            <li>Price: <%# Eval("Price") %></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <div>
                    Sorry, no products available
                </div>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
<div class="DataPager">
            <asp:DataPager ID="pager" PageSize="6" PagedControlID="category1" runat="server">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:NumericPagerField />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DataPager>
        </div>
```